# Dependent DLL in NuGet not copied to output directory of client

Tags: c#, nuget, csproj

I have a C# project which is packed to a NuGet package.
The project depends on an external non-managed dll and it is copied to the output just fine if I build the solution locally.
I already managed to get the dll packed in the NuGet package and it is put into the project of the client, but 'Copy to Output Directory' is always set to 'Do not Copy'.

I don't use a .nuspec file since I switched to the new .csproj format.

This is what my .csproj looks so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>External.Dll.Wrapper</PackageId>
    <Authors>Me</Authors>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Company>None</Company>
    <Owners>Me</Owners>
    <Copyright>Copyright © 2018</Copyright>
    <Description>Wrapper for using external dll</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>True</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="external.dll">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <CopyToOutput>true</CopyToOutput>
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
      <PackageFlatten>false</PackageFlatten>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.
I already spent a whole day trying to figure this out, with no luck.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't reference anything from that `dll` directly it won't get copied. If you put a dummy declaration somewhere (it doesn't even have to be used) then it should copy over.

```
externaldll.someclass mythingamajig
```

If that doesn't work, check the relative path of the dependency. Right click `Dependencies->Add reference->Browse->` then select the `dll` file and add it. You might have to add the `dll` manually for it to show up there.

Comment: Oh, and check the output path. It should be default if you haven't changed it but best to check to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I can't reference it since it's an unmanaged dll.